# Running ./configure file to install FFTW pacakage

Tags: 18.04

I have installed ubuntu app on windows 10. I am trying to install FFTW libraries by running. /configure file in ubuntu terminal. But it is showing that , "not found : ./configure " . [this is what i got after running ./configure command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoBP6.jpg)

Remember I am running ubuntu app on windows 10

Comment: what is ubuntu app?

Comment: Did you unpack the source code on your Windows system, using Windows tools? if so, the files may have Windows-style (CRLF) line endings

Comment: Please see: http://fftw.org/ "please note that FFTW 2.x was last updated in 1999 and it is obsolete. Please upgrade to FFTW 3.x." Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.